# WaitForSeconds и Coroutine (unity3D)

Tags: unity3d

Всех приветствую, такая проблема, что есть у меня скрипт, который висит на **UI элементе**.
В этом скрипте, запуск **анимации появления экрана или исчезновения**.
Когда идет запуск анимации появление экрана, срабатывает **WaitForSeconds**. И вот проблема. На одной сцене, этот скрипт работает **идеально**, а на другой, **после WaitForSeconds просто не работает дальше код**.

> ( Я уже пытался и поиграть с Time.timescale = 0, Time.timescale = 1. Ничего не помогает. )

**Вот сам код:**

```
public int SceneClose; // 1 - Сцена закрывается | 0 - Сцена открывается

private Animator animators;
void Start()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    StopAllCoroutines();
    animators = GetComponent<Animator>();
    StartScriptAnim();
}

private void StartScriptAnim()
{
    if (SceneClose == 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(StopAnim());
    }
    else if (SceneClose == 1)
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartAnim());
    }
}

IEnumerator StopAnim()
{
    animators.SetBool("IsOpen", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    SceneClose = 1;
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("NameScene");
    gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

IEnumerator StartAnim()
{
    animators.SetBool("IsOpen", false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    Debug.Log("Load");
    SceneManager.LoadScene("LoadScene");
}
```

**Может кто сможет помочь?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделай метод

```
void OnEnable()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}
```

и всё. Не нужно сначала делать таймСкейл 0 а потом 1. А Старт срабатывает 1 раз при запуске скрипта